# Should I check bash version?

Tags: bash

I'M using associative arrays in my script, which are available in bash version 4 and upwards. In terms of best practices, should I verify the version is at least 4? E.g. using `echo $BASH_VERSION | cut -d. -f1`.

Although bash 4 was released in early 2009, some OSes are still using older versions. E.g. the default bash on OS X is stuck on bash 3.2 (for legal reasons).

Comment: Simpler: `${BASH_VERSION%%.*}`

Comment: You don't have to modify it at all; just pattern match: `if [[ $BASH_VERSION == 4.* ]]`;

Comment: @chepner I actually like `(( ${BASH_VERSION%%.*} >= 4 ))`, it's future proof for versions 5+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Doing extra sanity checking is rarely a bad thing especially if there are reasonable situations where the check would fail and thereby prevent unexpected behavior.